# How can I determine the phases for a specific packaging type

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In Maven, when I use `<packaging>jar</packaging>`, I can see the default phases defined in

```
 ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.0.3/maven-core-3.0.3.jar/META-INF/plexus/components.xml
```

But when I use `<packaging>kar</packaging>` to build Apache Karaf project, how can I know the phases for package type of `kar`, which is not defined in `components.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

This is defined inside the [`karaf-maven-plugin`](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/karaf-maven-plugin.html). This plugin declares its own `components.xml`.

Taking the code [from GitHub](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/tooling/karaf-maven-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml), this is the lifecycle of the `kar` packaging:

```xml
<component>
    <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
    <role-hint>kar</role-hint>
    <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping</implementation>
    <configuration>
        <lifecycles>
            <lifecycle>
                <id>default</id>
                <phases>
                    <process-resources>
                        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources
                    </process-resources>
                    <compile>
                        org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:features-generate-descriptor
                    </compile>
                    <package>
                        org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:kar
                    </package>
                    <install>
                        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:install
                    </install>
                    <deploy>
                        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:deploy
                    </deploy>
                </phases>
            </lifecycle>
        </lifecycles>
    </configuration>
</component>
```

So this invokes:

- `process-resources` with `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources`
- `compile` with `org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:features-generate-descriptor`
- `package` with `org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:kar`
- `install` with `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:install`
- `deploy` with `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:deploy`

If you want to take a look at it inside your m2 repo, you should look inside (supposing you're using version 4.0.3)

```
 ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/tooling/4.0.3/karaf-maven-plugin-4.0.3.jar/META-INF/plexus/components.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `META-INF/plexus/components.xml` in the `karaf-maven-plugin.jar`.

```
<component>
        <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
        <role-hint>kar</role-hint>
        <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping</implementation>
        <configuration>
            <lifecycles>
                <lifecycle>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <phases>
                        <process-resources>
                            org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources
                        </process-resources>
                        <compile>
                            org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:features-generate-descriptor
                        </compile>
                        <package>
                            org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:kar
                        </package>
                        <install>
                            org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:install
                        </install>
                        <deploy>
                            org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:deploy
                        </deploy>
                    </phases>
                </lifecycle>
            </lifecycles>
        </configuration>
    </component>
```

The  role `org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping` defines the lifecycle configuration. The `role-hint` is the packaging type that you use in your pom.